# React Native, successfully setting state but wanting to save in asyncStorage at same time

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, mobile

I have a react native app module for tracking health statistics. This example is for weight, but when the dashboard loads there is an empty component with a button to trigger an editor modal. That gives a textInput where the user can enter their weight for the day, and when saved it saves that number to the state for that value and it now displays on the dashboard.

That works exactly as expected, but I want to also save that in asyncStorage at the same time along with the current date. I'm wanting to load state for the values if the current date matches a storage value for it but save it through the day.

Basically, if the user wakes up on Monday and logs their weight, I want it to display in the app all day but when they open it Tuesday it should be empty again for them to enter it for that day, and then THAT value should stay all day Tuesday, etc.

What do I need to do from here to achieve that?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text,  View, Dimensions, Button, ScrollView, TouchableOpacity, TextInput, Alert} from 'react-native';
import { Pedometer } from "expo-sensors";
import {
  LineChart,
  BarChart,
  PieChart,
  ProgressChart,
  ContributionGraph,
  StackedBarChart
} from "react-native-chart-kit";
import PedometerChart from './PedometerChart';
import Icon from '@expo/vector-icons/Ionicons';
import MatIcon from '@expo/vector-icons/MaterialCommunityIcons';
import NumericInput from 'react-native-numeric-input';
import Modal from 'react-native-modal';
import moment from 'moment';



export default class Dashboard extends Component{

    state = {
    weight:'',
    currentDate: new Date(),
    markedDate: moment(new Date()).format("YYYY-MM-DD")
  };

  render() {

    const today = this.state.currentDate;
    const day = moment(today).format("dddd");
    const date = moment(today).format("MMMM D, YYYY");

    return(
      <ScrollView>
      <View style={styles.container}>

      <View style={styles.mainContainer}>
        <View style={styles.widgetContainer}>
            <MatIcon  name="scale-bathroom" size={50} />
            <Text style={styles.titleText}>Weight</Text>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.widgetContainer}>
            <Text>
              <Text style={styles.textUnderlines}>
              {this.state.weight}
              </Text>
              <Text style={styles.recordsTypes}>
              lb
              </Text>
            </Text>
            <TouchableOpacity 
                style={styles.recordButton} 
                onPress={this.toggleWeightModal}
            >
            <Text style={styles.recordText}>Record</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      </View>

      <Modal 
          isVisible={this.state.isWeightModalVisible}
          backdropOpacity={0.7}
          onBackdropPress={() => this.setState({ isWeightModalVisible: false })}
      >
        <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
          <View style={styles.recordingModals}>
          <Text style={styles.titleText}>Weight for {date}</Text>
          <TextInput 
              value={this.state.weight}
              onChangeText={(weight) => this.setState({ weight })}
              keyboardType="numeric" 
              underlineColorAndroid="#000" 
              style={styles.modalInput} 
              placeholder="lbs"/>
          <TouchableOpacity style={styles.recordButtonModal} onPress={this.toggleWeightModal}>
          <Text style={styles.recordText}>Save Entry</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
        </View>
      </Modal>
      </ScrollView>
    ) ;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

can fetch today's date and store it in a variable. compare that variable and date from the state(this.state.today) if dates aren't same, empty weight container.

1. When weight container got updated, update date variable so It won't ask for weight again on the same day
   **OR** If the application runs all the time, reset weight container at 12 Night each day without any loops